# Google Sheet Formula

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I need a formula:   I have a row of numbers seperated by commas such as 1000, 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004 in A1 and I want to remove the commas but sort the values in A2- A6 each individually so 1000 Would go into A2 and 1001 would going to A3  Ect.

Comment: why have you tagged this with excel formula when you have Google sheet formula in the heading?. if you want to do this in excel, use Data | TextToColumns (from the data menu)

Answer (score 1):

1)In the data tab of Excel there is the text to columns tab. Select the delimited choice and separate your data by commas.

2) Copy your data and in cell A2 and transpose the data (after copying the data press `ctr + alt+ v` and select transpose.

3) Sort the data and you are done!

Answer (score 1):

If you mean in Google Spreadsheet, like your heading indicates, then here is the instructions (which I googled):

> In Google Sheets, paste your data into a column. You'll see a little
>   clipboard icon appear in the lower-right hand corner of your data.
>   Click on that, and you will see the option to split the data into
>   columns. Alternatively, if your data is already in your spreadsheet,
>   head up to the Data menu > Split text to columns